# Web scraping an address using Beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the address string from https://www.google.com.au/#q=Cat+Protection+NSW.

I was hoping that I could use something like this but it doesn't give any result.

```
soup.find_all("span",class_="_Xbe")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Scraping google results is against their ToS.

Comment: Is there another way I can use google search results that doesn't break their ToS?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/